# max/msp to ruby via udp message format

Tags: ruby, max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to build a little GUI with max/msp for a ruby project
I can't find a way to properly convert the data i receive form max.

here is several examples of message that i've received from max in ruby (i've send 2 first then 1 0 -1 -2):

```
["int\x00,i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02", ["AF_INET", 53802, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]]
["int\x00,i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", ["AF_INET", 53802, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]]
["int\x00,i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", ["AF_INET", 53802, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]]
["int\x00,i\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF", ["AF_INET", 53802, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]]
["int\x00,i\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE", ["AF_INET", 53802, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]]
```

so far i've been able to convert positive values to integer via String#ord or String#unpack but with those methods negative integers gives me 0 value

Comment: what's the issue , i am not getting... share your code please.

Comment: i just want to know how to convert first part of the message ("int\x00,i\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF") to integer in ruby, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Is this `"int\x00,i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02".ord
# => 105` you want ?

Comment: no this value should return => 2

Comment: the five messages in my question are received when i'm successively send 2, 1, 0, -1, -2 from max/msp. i just want to convert back to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with `#unpack`, using offset ('@8'), and 32-bit signed bigendian int ('l>')

```
str.unpack('@8l>')
```

I'm not sure what initial part of string means ("int\x00,i\x00\x00") and I have just ignored it with offset. It might need additional fiddling, if there is any important data.